# How to use Angular Material in Angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular-material2, angular5

I had just started learning angular 5. I need to use Angular Material for my form styling and layout.

Things done so far:
  1. npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
  2. imported the modules in @NgModule of app.module.ts and exported as well.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatStepperModule,
} from '@angular/material';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I want to use angular material tags in child component(register-component.html) of the root component(app-module). How to do that?

Comment: Are you using lazy-loaded modules?

Comment: While you are in the root folder of your project, type `ng --version` and check if you can see a line something like `Angular: 5.2.2` as proof indeed your project is configured for angular5. If it is 5, then follow according to 5. If it is 4 then follow according to 4.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Angular Material Docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) after you imported the all the modules from '@angular/material' also you have to add in inputs array of your app.module.ts:

`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

Make sure you have added theme of angular material to your `<project_folder>/src/app/styles.css` put:

`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';`

Now in your html:

`<button mat-button color="primary">Hello</button>`

- check if you have installed `@angular/cdk` package, which is also needed for this to work

Comment: I read it somewhere that animations is not necessary for all components, so I skipped it. Now I had installed and imported that as well. But still not working!!

Comment: Probably need more details to reproduce this issue, I am currently using: 

angular/cli 1.6.0, angular/core ^5.0.0, angular/material ^5.0.0 `

and everything works as expected. Although I am using shared module to import and export all angular/material depencies. Could you provide more details about your usage? Or a plunker example? Or screenshots of actual browser render, console errors, etc?